# How to store Pycharm logs in any document

Tags: python, pycharm

Hey Is there any possibility, that we can store all logs of our script running on pycharm in any text document?

Comment: You should take a look at [ask] and edit your question so it's clear what you're asking.

Comment: @TeSter Hey. You should mark the answer below correct. It isn't your fault pvg can't parse context

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to save logs from your scripts you can change settings for that with run configurations. See ->
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/setting-log-options.html

-- copied in case link expires in future -- taken from PyCharm 2017.3 version Help Desk --

To configure Logs options

1. In the Run/Debug Configuration dialog box, click Logs tab. The table
   Log files to be shown in console displays the list of log files (if
   any).
2. Click add. Edit Log Files Aliases Dialog dialog is displayed. In the
   Alias field, type the alias name to show in the list of log entries.
3. In the Log File Location field, type the fully qualified name of the
   log file, or specify its location by pressing the ellipsis button.
   Select whether you want to show all or last file coverable by
   pattern. Click OK to close the dialog.
4. Activate the log entry. To do that, select the checkbox in the Is
   Active column.
5. To skip the previous content, select the checkbox in the Skip
   Content column

Comment: Please mark this correct. your question was pretty clear to me, despite @pvg's inability to understand context. Cheers